VB.NET silently fails to compile code with `On Error Resume Next` + capturing closures
The following VB.NET console app fails to compile, and VS2022 doesn't show any error / warning:
Module Program
    Sub Main()
        On Error Resume Next                    '0
        Dim a As String
        Dim b = Sub(_a) Console.WriteLine(_a)   '1
        Dim c = Sub(_a) a = _a                  '2
    End Sub
End Module

Commenting out line '0 makes the program work, and so does commenting out '2.
'0 and '1 can work together, but '0 and '2 can't.

P.S. No need to tell me that On Error Resume Next is not recommended - I wouldn't like to use it. In fact, I personally prefer C# over VB.NET.
I'm just toying with VB to illustrate an idea that Golang-style error handling with if err != nil checks read just like legacy VB-style If Err.GetException() IsNot Nothing Then with On Error Resume Next being active.

Check your setting for Tools => Options... => Projects and Solutions => Build and Run => MSBuild project build output verbosity

@user246821 Actually the compiler error shows up in the Output window. It's just not showing up in the Error List

I just copied your code and built the project and got this in the Output window:

error BC36595: Method cannot contain both a 'On Error Resume Next' statement and a definition of a variable that is used in a lambda or query expression.

I don't know the inner workings of lambdas well enough to know exactly why that would be an issue but the error message is pretty clear.

I think it might be a VS2022 bug failing to show this error message.

@SunshineLi, it may not be listed in the Error List because they wouldn't be able to specify a single line number. In your case, there's three lines that create the error in combination and there could be more with additional variables and/or lambdas. Are you not seeing it in the Output window either or just not in the Error List? I'm using VS 2022 v17.10.1.

Ah I see, It's just not showing up in the Error List, but the Error List was eye-catching and I thought every error shows up in it……Good to know this might not be the case.
